# How to set only an offset when looping?

Tags: silverstripe

I have a situation where I need to start to loop through my images from the 7th image onwards e.g

```
// This shows the first 6 images

<% loop $GalleryImages.Limit(6) %>

    <img src="$Image">

<% end_loop %>
```

--

Then I need to show from the 7th image on wards. We can use the offset here but we have to set a limit (first parameter)

```
<% loop $GalleryImages.Limit(100, 6) %>

    <img src="$Image">

<% end_loop %>
```

Is there a way to just set the offset only or maybe another way I should tackle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cleanest thing to do is to create a method in your controller or model that runs the query.

```
public function OtherGalleryImages()
{
  return $this->GalleryImages()->limit(null, 6);
}
```

But I would question whether you really ever want to run an unlimited query, and for that reason, I think a simpler fix would be to just add a reasonable number into your `limit` on the template, as you have done. If you ever have more than 100, perhaps you have bigger problems than the expressiveness of your template syntax. :-)

Answer (score -3):

PHP's `array_slice` method allows you to specify a start, without know the length of the array.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

The advantage of using slice is that if the array is too short or too long, it will return an empty array instead of null, thus avoid errors

Comment: This circumvents the ORM and defeats lazy loading.